# Problema al abrir Docker en Windows

Tags: ubuntu, docker, windows10, instalacion, wsl

Acabo de instalar Docker y me sale esta ventana cuando ejecuto el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy al botón Finish, me sale esta ventana de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer creo que es problema de la versión del wsl que tengo, requiere de una versión 2, pero cuando verifico la versión sale que correctamente tengo la versión 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Volví a ejecutar el programa de Docker y nuevamente me salta la misma ventana de error:
[image: Error al abrir Docker]